# Getting error while checking if a file exists or not in SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl, ssis-2012

When I use the below script I get an error:

```
string filepath = Dts.Variables["user::Folderpath"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["user::Filename"].Value.ToString();
if (File.Exists(filepath)){
  Dts.Variables["user::fileexistflag"].Value = 1;
}
MessageBox.Show(filepath);
MessageBox.Show(Dts.Variables["user::fileexistingflag"].Value.ToString());
Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: script task to DFT.. i got the error at the script task level

Comment: What data type is fileexistflag?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. For somebody to be able to help you, you need to post the details of the error you are getting, not just your code.